# WIX - Unregister COM component during Uninstall

Tags: com, wix, merge-module

I have a couple of COM components which i register during installation. These COM components are part of a Merge Module which I include in my WIX project. I used used the below code for registering

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RegisterClassInfo/>
  <RegisterProgIdInfo/>
  <RegisterTypeLibraries/>
  <WriteRegistryValues/> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The components were registered successfully. However, during uninstallation, these COM components were not un-registered. How do I make sure that these components are un-registred when the SharedDLL Count is 1 before un-installation?

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, I just went through a whole bunch of hoops in regards to COM.

Really, you shouldn't be registering COM components on the system anymore. It causes way more problems than it solves. When you register COM components, you register them globally, potentially hi-jacking the component registration for that COM library from other applications. Hopefully, that won't happen, but you can't know that for sure.

Since Windows XP onwards, there has been something called *registry-free COM registration*. In order for this to work, you need to provide manifest files for each of the COM libraries in use by your application. You will also need to provide a manifest file for your application that states the app's dependencies on those COM libraries.

The beauty of this, is that you can deploy the COM libraries in your application's installation folder and no system registration is needed.

The following URLs can help you create the manifest files you'll need:

- [Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)
- [Simplify App Deployment with ClickOnce and Registration-Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx)
- [Manifest Files Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSI Writing Guidelines](http://wyrdfish.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/msi-writing-guidelines-this-may-be-out-of-date)

Let me know if you need any further information. I was able to successfully deploy my application with old VB6 COM components without registering them globally in the Windows registry and deploying the COM libraries in my application's installation folder (as opposed to `%windir%\system32` or `%windir%\SysWow64` (on 64-bit windows).